# How to reset redux store after each test using @testing-library/react in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, react-redux, jestjs, next.js, react-testing-library

I'm trying to get `@testing-framework/react` integrated into my Next.js workflow. To do that, I created a `test-utils.js` file as suggested in the documentation, where I re-export the render method with all my providers:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { ChakraProvider, ColorModeProvider } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import { Provider as ReduxStore } from 'react-redux';
import { useStore } from './lib/init-store';
import theme from './lib/theme';

const providersWrapper = ({ children }) => {
  // As pageProps.initialReduxState is undefined in _app.js
  const store = useStore(undefined);
  return (
    <ReduxStore store={store}>
      <ChakraProvider resetCSS theme={theme}>
        <ColorModeProvider
          options={{
            useSystemColorMode: true,
          }}>
          {children}
        </ColorModeProvider>
      </ChakraProvider>
    </ReduxStore>
  );
};

const customRender = (ui, options) =>
  render(ui, { wrapper: providersWrapper, ...options });

// re-export everything
export * from '@testing-library/react';

// override render method
export { customRender as render };
```

On the other hand, I have a Counter component and its tests:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { render, fireEvent, act, cleanup } from '../../test-utils';
import Counter from './index';

describe('Counter works properly', () => {
  test('it should increment count when +1 button is clicked', async () => {
    await act(async () => {
      const { findByText } = render(<Counter />);
      const initialCount = await findByText('0');
      expect(initialCount).toBeInTheDocument();
      const incrementButton = await findByText('+');

      fireEvent.click(incrementButton);
      const incrementedCount = await findByText('1');
      expect(incrementedCount).toBeInTheDocument();

      cleanup();
    });
  });

  test('it should decrement count when -1 button is clicked', async () => {
    await act(async () => {
      const { findByText } = render(<Counter />);
      const initialCount = await findByText('0');
      expect(initialCount).toBeInTheDocument();
      const decrementButton = await findByText('-');

      fireEvent.click(decrementButton);
      const decrementedCount = await findByText('-1');
      expect(decrementedCount).toBeInTheDocument();
      cleanup();
    });
  });
});
```

The jest setup works perfectly, but the second test, can't find a 0 text, because the state of the first test persists. I've confirmed this by swapping them resulting in the same: The first test passes, but the second fails.

This is weird, since the Testing Library documentation explicitly says that cleanup is called after each test automatically and by default (https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/setup/?fbclid=IwAR0CgDKrHalIhEUAEuP5S355uVYkTScMBATSIMgMPFcOz4ntsNCqgRA3Jyc#skipping-auto-cleanup).

So I'm a little bit lost here, I even tried to pull the celanup function out of render in both tests, and adding a `cleanup()` at the end of each test, having no different result.

Because of that, I thing that testing library is not the problem, instead, the redux store is not resetting after each test, causing the second test to read the state of the first. But I can't 100% prove it, and even if I could, I don't know how i'd reset it manually, since cleanup is supposed to happen automatically.

If you are curious, you can read the code of the whole project in this repo: https://github.com/AmetAlvirde/testing-library-redux-next-question/

I really hope you can help me, since being unable to test my code is something I really don't want to live with.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Maybe store is not re created because of [useMemo](https://github.com/AmetAlvirde/testing-library-redux-next-question/blob/main/lib/init-store.js#L40) you could try `const store = useStore(undefined,{}); ` then in useStore have it take the second argument and pass it to the [dependencies](https://github.com/AmetAlvirde/testing-library-redux-next-question/blob/main/lib/init-store.js#L41)

Comment: @HMR Thanks for your response. I tried removing the memoization by returning `initializeStore(initialStore)` instead of `memoizedStore` to see if that was the problem, but unfortunately it is'nt. 

Also, my `useStore` receive only the `initialState`, which I sent as undefined in the original code. When you suggested me to pass `useStore(undefined, {})` I get that the `undefined` represents the initial state of the store, but, what's the meaning of the second parameter? am I missing something? Thanks again.

Comment: The second parameter is to invalidate the cache. In your production code this would always be undefined but in your test it will always be a new reference to an object. But I see that you only ever create [one store](https://github.com/AmetAlvirde/testing-library-redux-next-question/blob/main/lib/init-store.js#L18). Maybe pass the second argument to `initializeStore` as well so when you test you create the store every time.